# Why an 'ON' clause is required in a left outer join

Tags: sql, join, syntax, left-join, outer-join

As far as I understand in a left outer join between two tables (say a & b) all the rows of the table on the left side of the join are retrieved regardless of the values in the rows on the right table. Then why do we need an 'ON' clause specifying a condition, something like this:

```
select * from a LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.some_column1 = b.some_column2;
```

Why is there a need for the statement "a.some_column1 = b.some_column2".

Comment: What version of SQL? Standard SQL requires inner & outer join to have an on.

Answer (score 6):

A `left join` would return all the rows from table `a`, and for each row the matching row in table `b`, if it exists - if it doesn't, `null`s would be returned instead of `b`'s columns. The `on` clause defines how this matching is done.

Comment: So if i do not specify the 'ON' clause then what will it give?

Answer (score 2):

An `on` clause is required since you are "joining", and you need to tell which columns you want to join by. Otherwise you would use traditional `from` without any `where` condition to all possible row combinations. But you wanted a join, right?

Yeah, that's pretty much it is.

Comment: "traditional `from` without any `where` condition" is still a join--"implicit join"--a cross join.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand in a left outer join between two tables (say a & b) all the rows of the table on the left side of the join are retrieved regardless of the values in the rows on the right table.

That is correct in the sense that it says something about what `left join on` returns, but it isn't a [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097) of what it returns. `left join on` returns `inner join on` rows plus (`union all`) unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.

`inner join on` returns the rows of `cross join` that satisfy the `on` condition--which could be any condition on the columns. `cross join` returns every combination of a row from the left table & a row from the right table.

What do you expect `outer join` without `on` to mean? In standard SQL `outer` & `inner` `join` have to have an `on`. `inner join` `on` a true condition is the same as `cross join`. Which has no unmatched left table rows. So if you want `outer join` with no `on` to mean `outer join` `on` a true condition then, since there are no unmatched rows in the `inner join` `on` that condition, the result is also just `cross join`. (MySQL allows `inner join` to be used without an `on`, but it just means `cross join`.)